How to create accessible hierarchy of anonymous objects in kotlin?
In testing purpose I want to create hierarchy of objects without creating multiple classes, something like that:
class Hierarchy {
    val root = object {
        val child1 = object {
            ...
        }
        val child2 = object {
            ...
        }
        ....
    }
}

The problem is, when I write
val hierarchy = Hierarchy()
hierarchy.root.child1 // error is here because hierarchy.root has type Any

it is not being compiled until I make field root private:
class Hierarchy {
    private val root = object {
        val child1 = {
            ...
        }
        val child2 = {
            ...
        }
    }
}

But when it's private it means I can not access it outside the class. May be there is some tricky way to make access to private field root as though I access it inside class Hierarchy?
